# Is there an existing template for a new C++ Open Source project

Tags: c++, qt, open-source

I want to start a new C++ (Qt) Open Source project and I'm wondering if there is an existing template somewhere for files usually found in an Open Source project but that are not purely  source code (README, LICENSE, CHANGELOG, etc.)

I could probably find a popular Open Source project for inspiration but if there is some existing generic templates, I will use that instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place to look might be the implementation of the [GNU Hello](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/) program. It includes all the standard template files expected by the GNU coding guidelines.

You may, of course, choose to follow another set of guidelines than GNU's.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the boost sandbox template interesting: [Sandbox Template](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/SandboxTemplate)